# Is there a numpy.polyfit like multivariate curve fitting function?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a polynomial curve with two different variables having two different dataset.

Here's my code snippet which works for one set of dataset, m1 and d1

```
import numpy as np

poly1 = np.polyfit(m1, d1, 2)
c_fit1 = np.poly1d(poly1)
```

Is there any numpy function for multivariate curve fitting with two set of dataset m1,m2 and d1,d2?